# Can a brane contain different Calabi-Yau compactifications in various areas?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-tunneling, branes, multiverse, string-theory-landscape

In Brian Greene's book *The Hidden Reality* he discusses the string landscape, and the possibility of it leading to a multiverse. In short, a universe with 3 large dimensions such as ours would contain all of the extra dimensions as CY manifolds. In certain areas, quantum tunneling changes the CY shape, and therefore the energy of that region to a lower state, nucleating a "bubble universe". This process occurs repeatedly in different areas, fleshing out the landscape.

There is also an article on Scientific American covering this same idea.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-string-theory-landscape/

It is my understanding that a brane such as the one that could contain our universe has compact extra dimensions. Would the above scenario be possible in a brane world picture? Fluctuations creating regions on the brane with different compactifcations and energy states creating bubbles?